# Hints timeouts in system.log in Apache cassandra 2.2.8

Tags: cassandra

We had the network outage b/w 2 data centers for few hours and connectivity was stabilized after that.

After that I see Hints timeout failures b/w **DC 1 to DC 2**. putting some failures here from logs

```
INFO  [HintedHandoff:2] 2018-05-17 15:27:30,286 HintedHandOffManager.java:367 - Started hinted handoff for host: 3623ef5c-08c9-4614-be7a-3971cd3157fb with IP: /10.166.242.xx
INFO  [HintedHandoff:1] 2018-05-17 15:27:51,603 HintedHandOffManager.java:486 - Failed replaying hints to /10.166.242.30; aborting (80 delivered), error : Operation timed out - received only 0 responses.
INFO  [HintedHandoff:1] 2018-05-17 15:27:51,635 HintedHandOffManager.java:367 - Started hinted handoff for host: d229bbd4-b883-4d46-b273-dbabd8b78772 with IP: /10.166.242.xx
INFO  [HintedHandoff:1] 2018-05-17 15:28:56,194 HintedHandOffManager.java:486 - Failed replaying hints to /10.166.242.29; aborting (111 delivered), error : Operation timed out - received only 0 responses.
INFO  [HintedHandoff:1] 2018-05-17 15:37:07,118 HintedHandOffManager.java:367 - Started hinted handoff for host: 276f819a-3e13-4303-bcb8-ea966f192a83 with IP: /10.166.242.xx
INFO  [HintedHandoff:2] 2018-05-17 15:37:20,402 HintedHandOffManager.java:486 - Failed replaying hints to /10.166.242.32; aborting (5631 delivered), error : Operation timed out - received only 0 responses.
INFO  [HintedHandoff:2] 2018-05-17 15:37:20,440 HintedHandOffManager.java:367 - Started hinted handoff for host: 1816dab4-63e0-4a98-8d92-2d413aa5785e with IP: /10.166.242.xx
INFO  [HintedHandoff:2] 2018-05-17 15:39:04,480 HintedHandOffManager.java:486 - Failed replaying hints to /10.166.242.33; aborting (510 delivered), error : Operation timed out - received only 0 responses.
INFO  [HintedHandoff:2] 2018-05-17 15:39:04,585 HintedHandOffManager.java:367 - Started hinted handoff for host: ba41044a-906b-448c-9637-3b2ce9061d90 with IP: /10.166.242.xx
INFO  [HintedHandoff:1] 2018-05-17 15:41:08,825 HintedHandOffManager.java:486 - Failed replaying hints to /10.166.242.34; aborting (1151 delivered), error : Operation timed out - received only 0 responses.
INFO  [HintedHandoff:1] 2018-05-17 15:41:08,893 HintedHandOffManager.java:367 - Started hinted handoff for host: ced8cd4f-bc13-4bef-978c-42023def6139 with IP: /10.166.242.xx
INFO  [HintedHandoff:1] 2018-05-17 15:42:11,205 HintedHandOffManager.java:486 - Failed replaying hints to /10.166.242.30; aborting (255 delivered), error : Operation timed out - received only 0 responses.
INFO  [HintedHandoff:1] 2018-05-17 15:42:11,253 HintedHandOffManager.java:367 - Started hinted handoff for host: d229bbd4-b883-4d46-b273-dbabd8b78772 with IP: /10.166.242.xx
INFO  [HintedHandoff:1] 2018-05-17 15:43:27,961 HintedHandOffManager.java:486 - Failed replaying hints to /10.166.242.29; aborting (82 delivered), error : Operation timed out - received only 0 responses.
INFO  [HintedHandoff:1] 2018-05-17 15:48:59,768 HintedHandOffManager.java:367 - Started hinted handoff for host: 276f819a-3e13-4303-bcb8-ea966f192a83 with IP: /10.166.242.xx
INFO  [HintedHandoff:1] 2018-05-17 15:51:30,948 HintedHandOffManager.java:486 - Failed replaying hints to /10.166.242.34; aborting (383 delivered), error : Operation timed out - received only 0 responses.
INFO  [HintedHandoff:1] 2018-05-17 15:51:30,978 HintedHandOffManager.java:367 - Started hinted handoff for host: 1816dab4-63e0-4a98-8d92-2d413aa5785e with IP: /10.166.242.xx
```

But from **DC2 to DC1** hints are replaying successfully with minimal failures.

```
INFO  [HintedHandoff:1] 2018-05-17 15:09:11,082 HintedHandOffManager.java:367 - Started hinted handoff for host: e37d2fc9-71e8-4dbb-8a96-8215f7b31749 with IP: /10.166.18.XX
INFO  [HintedHandoff:2] 2018-05-17 15:09:11,082 HintedHandOffManager.java:367 - Started hinted handoff for host: e0078d7f-6189-4485-b78b-9274b159de81 with IP: /10.166.18.XX
INFO  [HintedHandoff:2] 2018-05-17 15:09:11,847 HintedHandOffManager.java:399 - Finished hinted handoff of 4 rows to endpoint /10.166.18.XX
INFO  [HintedHandoff:2] 2018-05-17 15:09:11,862 HintedHandOffManager.java:367 - Started hinted handoff for host: 849533cd-59ed-4be5-9437-3880c639b2bc with IP: /10.166.18.XX
INFO  [HintedHandoff:2] 2018-05-17 15:09:12,378 HintedHandOffManager.java:399 - Finished hinted handoff of 31 rows to endpoint /10.166.18.XX
INFO  [HintedHandoff:2] 2018-05-17 15:09:12,393 HintedHandOffManager.java:367 - Started hinted handoff for host: 9f6a0ab3-7070-440b-a0e3-53f380ea680c with IP: /10.166.18.XX
INFO  [HintedHandoff:2] 2018-05-17 15:09:18,042 HintedHandOffManager.java:399 - Finished hinted handoff of 65 rows to endpoint /10.166.18.XX
INFO  [HintedHandoff:2] 2018-05-17 15:09:18,056 HintedHandOffManager.java:367 - Started hinted handoff for host: 91dc4605-829a-4ce1-8bfa-52f3b9edb8ec with IP: /10.166.18.XX
INFO  [HintedHandoff:1] 2018-05-17 15:09:19,856 HintedHandOffManager.java:399 - Finished hinted handoff of 11 rows to endpoint /10.166.18.XX
INFO  [HintedHandoff:2] 2018-05-17 15:09:19,925 HintedHandOffManager.java:399 - Finished hinted handoff of 1 rows to endpoint /10.166.18.XX
INFO  [HintedHandoff:1] 2018-05-17 15:39:11,087 HintedHandOffManager.java:367 - Started hinted handoff for host: 9f6a0ab3-7070-440b-a0e3-53f380ea680c with IP: /10.166.18.XX
INFO  [HintedHandoff:1] 2018-05-17 15:39:28,986 HintedHandOffManager.java:399 - Finished hinted handoff of 150 rows to endpoint /10.166.18.XX
INFO  [HintedHandoff:2] 2018-05-17 15:49:11,089 HintedHandOffManager.java:367 - Started hinted handoff for host: e37d2fc9-71e8-4dbb-8a96-8215f7b31749 with IP: /10.166.18.XX
INFO  [HintedHandoff:2] 2018-05-17 15:50:11,089 HintedHandOffManager.java:486 - Failed replaying hints to /10.166.18.52; aborting (0 delivered), error : Operation timed out - received only 0 responses.
INFO  [HintedHandoff:1] 2018-05-17 15:59:11,115 HintedHandOffManager.java:367 - Started hinted handoff for host: e37d2fc9-71e8-4dbb-8a96-8215f7b31749 with IP: /10.166.18.XX
INFO  [HintedHandoff:1] 2018-05-17 16:00:12,334 HintedHandOffManager.java:399 - Finished hinted handoff of 1014 rows to endpoint /10.166.18.XX
```

So these Hints timeouts are happening because of network issue or something we should look into Cassandra?

Comment: It looks like you still have network connectivity issue.

Comment: Have you checked the current status of DC1? The exceptions caught in the [code](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/81b6c9e994d16e114457dafb85886e03e5d6d2a7/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/db/HintedHandOffManager.java#L486) are WriteTimeoutException|WriteFailureException. WriteTimeoutException it's a Cassandra timeout during a write query. WriteFailureException is a non-timeout error during a write query.
This happens when some of the replicas that were contacted by the coordinator replied with an error.

Comment: Thanks. this is happening because network bandwidth is not stable. Once the network is stable b/w DC's, hints replayed successfully without timeouts. After that we did repair and the cluster is in consistent state now.